# Using MySQL in C++ in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to use MySQL in my C++ program developed in Visual Studio 2019.

While trying include MySQL libraries with `#include <cppconn/driver.h>` (or anything else that is being included in the sample code in MySQL Documentation) it shows an error: "cannot open source file cppconn/driver.h".

So far I've installed and configured the following programs:

- MySQL Shell 8.0.22
- MySQL Connector C++ 8.0.22
- MySQL Installer for Windows - Community (used to install everything else)
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9
- MySQL Server 8.0.22
- MySQL Router 8.0.22
- MySQL Workbench 8.0.22 CE

I've already started a local MySQL server and the VS 2019 itself (not the programs written in it) can connect to it. Compiling C++ programs without MySQL also works fine.

I suspect that I need to show VS 2019 where to find these libraries, but I don't know how to do that. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Have you already done this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=msvc-160 ?

Comment: Have you followed the MySQL instructions for making it work with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

So I re-run the installation of MySQL Connector C++ and chose the custom setup option. The Dll libraries were included, but Development Components were not. I changed that and magically a whole set of .h files that I was looking for appeared under the new "MySQL_Connector_C++_8.0/include" directory. I've promptly added those under Include Directories of my project.